# Pass token to Authorization header in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm fairly new to react native so be gentle please :)

I need to pass a token to the authorization header - this is what i have just now which doesn't work:

```
const auth = new Buffer('username : <SECRETKEYHERE>');
const token = auth.toString('base64');
const authHeader = 'Basic ' + token;


fetch('https://example.com/get-token.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': authHeader,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
}).then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseText) => {
  alert(responseText);
  console.log(responseText);
})
```

(Note: The base64 conversion above works as expected and returns the correct base64 key, so that isn't the issue)

However, if i put the base64 key straight into the authorization header the request works as expected:

```
fetch('https://example.com/get-token.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic <BASE64KEYHERE>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
}).then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseText) => {
  alert(responseText);
  console.log(responseText);
})
```

I have searched SO and tried various solutions with no luck, main ones i have already looked at:

[Using an authorization header with Fetch in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203044/using-an-authorization-header-with-fetch-in-react-native)

[React native - FETCH - Authorization header not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144396/react-native-fetch-authorization-header-not-working)

If anyone can help or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated as i have spent a fair bit of time trying to get this to work with no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the format of HTTP Basic Authentication header is

```
Authorization:Basic <Base64EncodedAuthString>
```

where

```
Base64EncodedAuthString:=<username>:<password>
```

So I am wondering about the blanks before and after your colon in

```
const auth = new Buffer('username : <SECRETKEYHERE>');
```

, shouldn't it be

```
const auth = new Buffer('username:<SECRETKEYHERE>');
```

instead?

See also https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#page-5

Comment: i removed the blanks and i'm now getting a successful request. I should have tried that! haha. Thanks for your time